# Obtaining the maximum value of $x$ in terms of $b$ in the equation $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1≤b$ given the value of $b$

Tags: polynomials

How to find the maximum value that x can take given the value of b. Both x and b can take only nonnegative integer values.Is it possible?

Comment: If you make it an equation and solve for $x$ using the quartic formula (ugly, I know, but it is a way), then you have four potential values, and you can take the floor of whatever is the maximum of those in the reals. It will also tell you if the inequality has ANY solutions. This isn't perfect, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the sequence $\{a_n = n^4 + n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 \,| \, n\in \mathbb{N} \}$. If $b$ is between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ then $x_{max} = n$.